# Using Git with a Drupal site

Tags: version-control

May we use git with a Drupal Site ?

Because I'm trying to use Git with a Drupal site and it seems that not all the information that are pushed !!!

Thank you

Comment: Did someone set up the .gitignore file?  It might be ignoring some files, but that might be a good thing.  Most people don't want to shove Drupal core into the repo.

Comment: The .gitignore files are empty ... yeah it will be a very good thing -- I hope that it is possible!!

Comment: You're not trying to push website content with git, right? Just the code?

Comment: all the things, code and content ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Git is a source code management (SCM) system.  There are many different source code management systems out there and Git fall into the category of a distributed version control system (DVCS).  It takes a "peer-to-peer" approach to version control as opposed to a "Client-Server" approach like version control systems like Subversion (SVN).

Yes we can use GIT with drupal.

To setup a GIT repository in drupal project please visit below link.

[Git Setup](http://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/init.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is typical practice to manage Drupal with a VCS, with Git being the defacto option; Drupal core, as well as all projects on drupal.org, uses Git as its VCS.

Drupal includes some default git configurations. D7 has a [default .gitignore config](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/.gitignore?h=7.x). D8 has an [example.gitignore config](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/example.gitignore?h=8.2.x) which isn't applied by default. There is also a [default .gitattributes](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/.gitattributes?h=8.2.x) for white space settings.

You'll have to troubleshoot what is/is not include in your codebase. Typically, the gitignore settings exclude content & settings data from the code repo.

Comment: Oh !! where may I find the default drupal gitignore file ?? because this one is blocking the content to be updated  !

Comment: It's in the site root. BTW, using a VCS to store content is considered bad practice; a VCS is for managing code, not data. Putting all your content into your VCS can blow up its size pretty quickly depending on how much content you have.

Comment: So for the content I use "export and import" the database ?

Comment: There are many solutions out there, it will depend on your needs. The Drupal [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) project is one solution to migrating over both DB & file system content.

Comment: @ShawnConn my naive way of handling it was creating a separate repo and doing mysqldump, after i clear cache of course.